# Magento filter products by items that have this item in their related products

Tags: magento

I wish to get a collection of products that have product x as a related product.

So, say I'm starting with

```
$_productCollection = $product->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
->addStoreFilter()
->distinct(true);
```

And wish to add something like (but with some reverse `in` instead of `eq`):

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('related_ids',array('eq' => $idofproductx));
```

I can't find anything, but assume it will include a join of some description. I'd rather avoid loading all products and then all related for each cycling through them all, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do

```
// @var $products array
$_productCollection->getSelect()->join(array('links' => 'catalog_product_link'), 'e.entity_id = links.product_id');

$_productCollection->getSelect()->where('links.linked_product_id IN (?)', $products);
```

I tested that it runs without error against my DB, but I don't have product links in my database (we fetch from a web service), so I can't be certain it returns the expected products.

Comment: I ended up not needing this, and so haven't tested it. I will mark it as correct, and will change that if anyone comments to say otherwise. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue, but I ended up making a small module for this so it's reusable.
But for simplicity a stripped back version of my solution can be found below.

```
// load by a product Id
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);

$_linkInstance = $_product->getLinkInstance();
$collection = $_linkInstance->getLinkCollection();

// get products which have $_productId as a link
$collection->addFieldToFilter('linked_product_id',  array('eq' => $_product->getId()));

// 1 = related products
$collection->addLinkTypeIdFilter(1);
$collection->joinAttributes();
```

The above code will populate $collection with an array of IDs which have assigned $_productId as a related product.

**Note:** This works on CE 1.9.1.0